# Можно ли сохранить в bitmap содержимое layout'a?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bitmap

Можно ли сохранить в bitmap содержимое layout'a? Например, есть такая разметка

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ivPhotoAfter"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_height="324dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay">

        <TextView
            android:text=""
            tools:text="Наименование проекта"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvProjectName"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Можно это все сохранить в один bitmap и, если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно.

Согласно запросу в гугл

> [android get bitmap from layout](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20get%20bitmap%20from%20layout)

И [первой ссылке выдачи](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8120310/3212712)

делается это так:

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```